# Changing the shape and colour of boxplot outliers based on factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data:

```
set.seed(100)
test_data = data.frame(ID = rep(1:100, 2), 
                       status = rep(c(0,1,0,1), each = 50), 
                       variable = rep(c("var1", "var2"), each = 100), 
                       value = rnorm(n = 200))
```

I want to plot this data as a boxplot like so:

```
ggplot(test_data) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = reorder(variable, value, FUN = median), y = value))
```

But I would like to change the shape and/or colour of the outliers depending on the status column. So if the point had status 1 then it is a red circle and if it is status 0 then it is a blue dot, for example.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
for (i in names(table(test_data$variable))) {
  for (j in c(0, 1)) {
    iqr = quantile(test_data[test_data$variable %in% i & test_data$status %in% j, 
                             "value"], c(0.25, 0.75))
    whisker = iqr + c(-1.5, 1.5) * diff(iqr)
    test_data[, "shape"] <- ifelse(test_data[test_data$variable %in% i & 
                                   test_data$status %in% j, "value"] < whisker[1] 
                                   | 
                                   test_data[test_data$variable %in% i & 
                                   test_data$status %in% j, "value"] > whisker[2], 
                                   1, 16)
  }
}
test_data_shape = test_data[test_data$shape %in% 1, ]
test_data_shape$shape = ifelse(test_data_shape$status %in% 1, 15, 16)

ggplot(test_data) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = reorder(variable, value, FUN = median), 
                                     y = value)) + 
geom_point(data = test_data_shape, aes(x = reorder(variable, value, FUN = median), 
                                       y = value, shape = factor(shape))) +
scale_shape_manual(guide=FALSE, values=c("16" = 16, "15" = 15))
```

Comment: Your loop isn't doing what you need. The line `test_data[, "shape"] <- ...` needs some row indexing. As it is, you are overwriting the whole `shape` column with (silent) vector recycling.

Comment: Yer I know. I figured this out in the end. I need to add an answer.